# Web Intelligence : line chart method

Tags: business-objects, webi

I'm trying to make a line chart on WebI 4.2 Support Pack 4 Compilation : 14.2.4.2410. 
I have an array with my number of order for each month.

`+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 | 165 | 221 | 150 | 214 | 105 |  18 | 115 |  15 | 201 |  26 | 102 | 101 |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+`

For exemple I use this function in my measures changing the month at the end to get my total of orders.

`=Number([Id]) In ([Date]) Where (Month(ToDate([Date]; "dd/MM/yy")) ="january")`

How can I get a line chart with my months in x-coordinate and my number of orders in y-coordinate ? I think that I'm totally wrong in my method cause I really don't find how to use line chart correctly.
Should I have my months as dimension variables ?

I do not have the right to post pictures yet to illustrate what I want and sorry for my english level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are making this more difficult that it needs to be. It seems like you do not have the Month name in your data. So create a variable to get that. If the object containing your date is a Date data type it would look like this...

```
Month=Month([Date])
```

If your date is a string you would do something like this...

```
Month=Month(ToDate([Date]; "dd/MM/yy"))
```

If you don't have a measure for your number of orders you will need a variable counting them...

```
Number of Orders=Count(ID)
```

Then create a table with Month and Number of Orders. Create a custom sort order if you want the months in chronological order. You can easily create a line chart by right-clicking on your table and choosing "Turn Into > Line Chart".

I did this with a Calendar table I have with a count of the number of days in each month in 2019.

[image]

Comment: Great ! My two functions were wrong as you said. I need to get all months in a variable and that work perfectly with the second function.